# HTML5 datepicker

Tags: html

I need help to create a drop down for day to pick from. Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a website for asking specific queries relating to programming problems, not for finding software libraries or plugins.

Comment: Yes, there is. But we're not here to Google for you ;)

Comment: In which case you should share what you've already tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: The form controls in HTML are what they are. Everything else requires JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

using javascript you can populate that field
toget number of days in that month can use

```
var date = new Date()
```

which is javascript function which will give you today's date 
and then use

```
  date.getMonth()
  date.getYear()
```

to get today's month and year

```
//Month is 1 based
 function daysInMonth(month,year) {
return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

//July
daysInMonth(7,2009); //31 
//February
daysInMonth(2,2009); //28
daysInMonth(2,2008); //29
```